# Implementing solr in pyramid framework in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, solr, pyramid

How to implement **solr** in python framework **Pyramid** in **Eclipse IDE**? Also how to instantiate a Document for indexing database records in python for Solr. What are python wrappers and does this implementation require them?

Comment: google it. https://pythonhosted.org/solrpy/

Comment: @TomWillis I have an existing app in pyramid running in eclipse that renders me clueless. I looked into sunburnt but dont know how to integrate solr using sunburnt into my Pyramid based web app. Any pointers regarding that. Didnt find much on google.